# Efficiency question in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this HTML structure in a page and an AJAX request returns the same structure:

```
<div id="feeds">
    <div class="items">
        <div class="feedClass">
            content
        </div>
        <div class="feedClass">
            content
        </div>
        <div class="feedClass">
            content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pager">
        content
    </div>
    <div class="keys">
        content
    </div>
</div>
```

Contents of data are the same as above.

How can I replace this JavaScript code with a more efficent code to append the stuff in items to the current items, and replace the content in pager and keys. I have this so far, `data` is what is returned by the AJAX request:

```
var itemsFirstChildTag = $(id + " .items:first-child").get(0).nodeName;

var id = "#feeds";

$(".items", id).append($(id + " .items > "+itemsFirstChildTag, "<div>"+data+"</div>"));

$(".keys", id).replaceWith($(id + ".keys", "<div>"+data+"</div>"));

$(".pager", id).replaceWith($(id + ".pager", "<div>"+data+"</div>"));
```

Comment: your single quotes are all messed up. and could you show the actual data in `data`?

Comment: Your JS code has typos. Is this your actual JS?

Comment: Hi guys,
 the contents of data is what the ajax request returns and the html structure is the same as the html fragment above but with different content for .items, .pager and .keys.

Comment: Why not just replace the contents of the body tag, if you return the entire html structure?

Comment: The thing is that i want to append the stuff on .items so that it will keep growing.

Answer (score 0):

I would try looking into using a better communication method, such as JSON or XML.  That alone would make this whole ajax request a LOT more efficient.  The idea being you can append the `data` you are returning to the appropriate location, you do not need to be returning any HTML.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'some-script.php',
  success: function( response ){
      //neat jquery element creation
      var newFeed = $("div", {
         "class" : "feedClass",
         "text" : response.newText
      });

      $(".items").append(newFeed);
      $(".keys").text(response.newText);
  }
});
```

If you need to modify the text of an element you can use [**.text()**](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

**Get:**

```
$(".some-class").text();
```

**Set:**

```
$(".some-class").text("Some Text");
```

If you need to modify the HTML of an element, use [**.html()**](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

GET/SET same as `$.text()`

---

**In short I'd definitely recommend reading as much of the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/) as you possibly can, there are a lot of neat tricks/demo's there.**

Answer (score 0):

var feeds = document.getElementById("feeds"); 
var feeddivs = feeds.getElementsByTagName("div");
var len = feeddivs.length; 
for(var i=0;i

}